# Prediction/generalisation error derivation

Tags: machine-learning, variance

In section 7.3 of "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman 2009) one can find the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKbnD.jpg]

**I am at a loss at how to get from the first to the second line, and how to get from the second to the third line in the derivation:**

1. In line 2, I get the first and second term, but the third appears out of nowhere: I only get $E\left[\hat{f}^2\right]$ for the third term when I expand the first line.
2. In line 3, how does the variance follow from line 2? Is this a typo in line 2? In my book, $\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{f}\right) = E\left[\left(\hat{f}-E\hat{f}\right)^2\right]$, not $\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{f}\right)=\left(E\left[\hat{f}-E\hat{f}\right]\right)^2$ as suggested.

Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: About 2: this is a matter of notation: by $E[Z]^2$ one should understand $E^2[Z]$: notice that in the text the symbol $[$ is after $E$, and note before it.

Comment: @madness I agree on the interpretation but it's a terrible notation. Also note, a symbol [ before the $E$ would give it yet another meaning. The reasoning can thus not serve to resolve the ambiguity of the notation.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

OK, I got it:

$E[(Y-\hat{f})^2] = E[\epsilon^2 + 2f\epsilon -2\epsilon\hat{f} + f^2 - 2f\hat{f} + \hat{f}^2]$

$E[(Y-\hat{f})^2] = \sigma_\epsilon^2 + f^2 - 2fE\hat{f} + E[\hat{f}^2]$

Note that:

$E[(\hat{f}-E\hat{f})^2] = E[\hat{f}^2] - 2E\hat{f}E\hat{f} + (E[\hat{f}])^2$

$E[(\hat{f}-E\hat{f})^2] = E[\hat{f}^2] - (E[\hat{f}])^2$

It follows:

$E[(Y-\hat{f})^2] = \sigma_\epsilon^2 + f^2 - 2fE\hat{f} + (E[\hat{f}])^2 + E[(\hat{f}-E\hat{f})^2]$

$E[(Y-\hat{f})^2] = \sigma_\epsilon^2 + (E[\hat{f}]-f)^2 + E[(\hat{f}-E\hat{f})^2]$